# Prime Numbers and Elliptic Equations

Tags: elliptic-curves

I came across one elliptic equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 + p^2$ being $p$ prime, and taking $p \neq 3$, I want to have more understanding why there is no rational point $x$, for $y = 3p$ or $y = 3p^2$, such that:

$$y^2 = x^3 + p^2$$

I want to know in terms of equivalence classes approach also if possible.

Comment: (x,y) are points of the affine space, that's what the question tells us.

Comment: The question does not seem to make sense? You are asking for rational $x$, which never appears again... If you are asking for rational points on $E:y^2 = x^3 + p^2$, then e.g., $p = 11$ this curve has rank $1$. If you are looking for a $y$ satisfying the equation, then $27p^4 + 1$ resp. $27p + 1$ is a square. The second occurs when $p = 29$ and the first always breaks mod $16$.

Comment: Actually you are right and I explain now better.

Comment: And for the other, is there any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y^2 = x^3 + p^2$;

- take $y=3p$ place into equation; $9p^2 = x^3 + p^2$ then $x^3 = 8p^2$ take the cube-root; $x=2\sqrt[3]{p^2}$, this implies there is no rational solution.
- take $y=3p^2$ place into equation; $9p^4 = x^3 - p^2$ then we have $$x^3 - (9p^4 + p^2)$$ Look at the discrimant $\Delta_x = -27 (9p^4-p^2)^2$. It is negative, therefore, one real two complex roots. Complext roots cannot be a solution. The real root is $p^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{9p^2-1}$. This concludes that no rational solution here, too.

Comment: Why x | p? Could you explain this part?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo okay, there is a better way to see that. I've updated.

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get to the discriminant in this form? Also, I want to ask if it was $y = 1$, how to proceed.

Comment: 3rd degree formula. Look at the Wikipedia.